# Gesture Recognizers Not Working In Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

My swipe gesture recognizer is not working when I add it to Storyboard. I've been presenting the new view programmatically so far, but I like Storyboard segues since the preserve the same instance of the previous view controller. I've attached a Swipe Gesture Recognizer to my view ("Home") and control-dragged a segue to another view ("Notes") but when I attempt to swipe on the simulator, I don't get any response. I've set the delegate as my main view ("Home"). A method,  "gesture_TestSwipe" simply contains an NSLog, which also does not display in the console. I can't post images, but I can try to clarify any confusions. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You implement on .m file your recognizer ?

Comment: "I've been presenting the new view programmatically so far, but I like Storyboard segues since the preserve the same instance of the previous view controller." -- there should be no difference in preserving the same instance of the previous controller between presenting the new view programmatically or via a segue. If you're getting different behavior using the two approaches, then you're doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @rdelmar Perhaps I am. I think its because every time I pop back to my root view controller I'm creating a new instance of the class. Would you happen to know exactly what the "< back" button for a navigation controller does programmatically? I believe that would solve my problem.

Comment: That certainly shouldn't happen with the default back button, if that's what you're talking about. The root view controller of a navigation controller should not be deallocated unless the navigation controller itself is. The back button just performs  popViewControllerAnimated:.